# redirect users if already logged in to home page spring boot security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am having a spring boot application where users can log in and access the login. After logging in, the users can still access the login page. I want the logged users don't have access to the login page, instead redirect them to the home page. How can I do this?? I am using spring security to authenticate the users.

This is my current configuration:

```
    http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/css/**","/js/**","/register/**").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
    .permitAll()
    .and()
    .logout()
    .logoutUrl("/logout")
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
    .permitAll()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use filter, in your login controller @GetRequest("/login") check the user details by principal.getName() and return home view if it's not null.

Comment: Please mark it as correct answer if it works for you, thanks :)

Comment: I did not ask this question. :)

Comment: oh, sorry, I just noticed the same surname :)

Comment: I am not using any controller for login, spring-security is handling the login part 
@k-wasilewski

Comment: Ok, so my advice'd be: simply create one, it's quite simple https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.0.M2/guides/html5/form-javaconfig.html